# Why should I use std::cerr instead of std::cout in exception Handling?

Tags: c++, exception

Is there any significant advantage of using `std::cerr` instead of `std::cout` in the below snippest

```
try{
     //codes that can throw go here. 
}std::catch(std::exception const& e) {
std::cerr << "Exception " << e.what();
}
```

.

Comment: Which question do you want to know the answer to?

Comment: "Is it a bad idea using exception Handling for local error recovery" - Entirely opinion based. Depends on the program in question and depends on who you ask. Different people will have different opinions for different pieces of code. A objective, definite, fact based answer, is impossible.

Comment: Generally the first question is opinion based. What you should however never do is misuse exceptions for validating frequent input. Catching an exception is often significantly slower than the check alone. An exception should be a rare exception. As for cout vs cerr, you should use cerr when that error will ever be seen by another application (like if you write a software that will be called by other siftware) because then that software can automatically separate regular output for error output. Also some consoles display cerr in red so it is more obviously disinguishible from regular output.

Comment: Okey dokey. Thanks for editing. I cast the first reopen vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "err" in `cerr` is short for "error". It's intended for error messages. It writes to the error output stream, which, on UNIX-like systems, still writes to the console when you redirect the standard output stream. When you redirect output to a file, you usually don't want error messages intertwingled with the normal output and sent to the file.

Comment: `std::cerr` is also flushed to the OS immediately, unlike `std::cout`.

Comment: Does it take too much time for the characters to be flushed?

Comment: @Lexshard -- if your program crashes you'll be glad that the output was flushed, because you'll be able to see it.